# jQuery: Transform dynamically added textbox into a normal label

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of movies with many tags. My goal is to have a button to add new tags, which will create a TextBox where (later with autocomplete) new tags can be added. After pressing the enter button (or clicking on a save Icon inside the TextBox), I want to save that tag to the database and remove the TextBox and add the new tag as a normal `<li>` Element

[image]

HTML/Razor view:

```
<span id="tags">Tags:</span>
<ul class="tags" data-movie="@movie.ID">
    @if (movie.Tags != null)
    {
        foreach (var tag in movie.Tags)
        {
            <li>@tag.Name</li>
        }
    }
    <li class="addTag">
       <a id="addTagLink" data-movie="@movie.ID">Add</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    //Revealing Module Pattern

    var dataService = new function (ID) {
        addTagForMovie = function (ID, Tag) {
            $.getJSON('/Movies/addTagForMovie/',
                { ID: ID, Tag: Tag }, function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        // remove TextBox, add new tag as <li> element
                    } 
                }); 
        };
        
        return {
            addTagForMovie: addTagForMovie
        };
   }(); 

   var tagManager = new function () {

        addTagForMovie = function (ID, Tag) {                
            dataService.addTagForMovie(ID, Tag);                

        }

        return {
            addTagForMovie: addTagForMovie // make function visible for the outside
        };
    }();

    // when the Add new link is clicked, add a new textbox
    $("ul.tags li.addTag a").click(function(e) {
        $(this).before("<input id=\"\" data-movie=\""+ $(this).data('movie') +"\" class=\"newTagBox\" type=\"test\">");

        // Enter was pressed inside the newly added Input box
        $('input.newTagBox').keyup(function (e) {                
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {                    /
                addTagForMovie($(this).data('movie'), $(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
```

Everything works great so far, the TextBox appears and after pressing enter, the tag is added through the MovieController into the database and I get a success or error result.

However, I don't know how and where I can delete the TextBox and add the `<li>NewTag Value</li>` element. Sure I can add `data-`- attributes to every tag and find the TextBox with jQuery, delete it and add a new element, however, this seems quite complicated.

Unfortunately, I cannot make the `getJSON` in such a way that it blocks untill it is finished and then remove the `$(this)` element which would be the Inputbox.

What is "best practice" to do something like that?
Is there anything else I could improve? I'm very new to Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Try using `var updatedContainer = $('.container'); $(document).on('change', function() {updatedContainer = $('.container'); });` where .container cam be w/e holds the dynamic inputs.

Comment: Sorry for short comment. On my android. But `updatedContainer` will always have anything added to it to br later modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You need to append the tag value to `tags` list and clear the input text value

Like

```
// Enter was pressed inside the newly added Input box
$('input.newTagBox').keyup(function (e) {                
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {                    
        addTagForMovie($(this).data('movie'), $(this).val());
        $('ul.tags').append('<li>' + $(this).val() + '</li>'); //Append to tag list
        $(this).val(''); //Clear textbox value
    }
});
```

Example with callback method

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    //Revealing Module Pattern

    var dataService = new function (ID) {
        addTagForMovie = function (ID, Tag, cb) {
            $.getJSON('/Movies/addTagForMovie/',
                { ID: ID, Tag: Tag }, function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {

                        //Call callback method
                        cb();
                    } 
                }); 
        };

        return {
            addTagForMovie: addTagForMovie
        };
   }(); 

   var tagManager = new function () {

        addTagForMovie = function (ID, Tag, cb) {                
            dataService.addTagForMovie(ID, Tag, cb);
        }
        return {
            addTagForMovie: addTagForMovie // make function visible for the outside
        };
    }();

    // when the Add new link is clicked, add a new textbox
    $("ul.tags li.addTag a").click(function(e) {
        $(this).before("<input id=\"\" data-movie=\""+ $(this).data('movie') +"\" class=\"newTagBox\" type=\"test\">");

        // Enter was pressed inside the newly added Input box
        $('input.newTagBox').keyup(function (e) {                
            if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
                var self = this;
                addTagForMovie($(this).data('movie'), $(this).val(), function(){
                    $('ul.tags').append('<li>' + $(self).val() + '</li>'); //Append to tag list
                    $(self).val(''); //Clear textbox value
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about that, however, the addTagForMovie Call does not wait until it's finished. So the tag will be added, even if something goes wrong on the server-side and the tag couldn't be saved to the DB.

Comment: @user66875, You can use callback method to perform append tag and clear textbox of sucess method of `if (data.success) {`

Comment: @user66875, I have updated answer with callback example

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did work great! I just had to change ` $(self).before('<li>' + $(self).val() + '</li>'); ` cause otherwise, the tag was added to the taglist of every movie.